# Column Chart to show multiple series per Label

Tags: html, css, highcharts

[image]Help to draw a column chart, to map each Label with different series. For example.

```
X Axis : China, UK, India

Y Axis: 
For China: 1,2,3,4

For UK: 1,2,3

For India: 1,2
```

For each X axis label I need different labels. In case of China I need 4 labels, In case of UK I need 3 labels and in case of India I need 2 labels.

Thanks, One more rquirement I am struggling to put it that on place. The X axis should be in following format, please see Image and also it should be responsive Graph.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're not looking for a grouped chart, what you're really doing here is plotting three different charts.

However, for convenience sake, we can combine them into one chart, with three separate x axes.

**Example code**:

```
xAxis: [{
  offset:0,
  left:100,
  width:160,
  tickInterval:1,
  title: { text: 'China' }
},{
  offset:0,
  left:290,
  width:120,
  tickInterval:1,
  title: { text: 'UK' }
},{
  offset:0,
  left:440,
  width:80,
  tickInterval:1,
  title: { text: 'India' }
}]
```

**Example Fiddle**:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/v3en6p9b/

**Example Image**:

[image]

Or, there is the "**Grouped Categories**" plugin which may also suit your needs:

- http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories

Comment: Cheers, Much Appreciated . Please can you help me to make column looks like in above Image and also graph should be responsive.